# Aligning substrings in NSAttributedString

Tags: nsattributedstring

I'm writing an attributed string to a UITextView. It has a left-aligned text substring, followed by a line number. I want that line number to be right-aligned.

I tried applying an NSParagraphStyle to the citation string and then appending the citation string to the text string.

```
let alignStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
alignStyle.alignment = .right
let citationAttributes: Dictionary<NSAttributedString.Key, Any> = [
   .paragraphStyle: alignStyle]
let citationString = NSAttributedString(string: citation, attributes: citationAttributes)
textLine.append(citationString)
```

I expected to see the citation neatly aligned to the right margin, on the same line as the text. But instead, it occurs immediately at the end of the text string. 
Is there some way to achieve the formatting result I want with an attributed string?

Comment: Can you show a rough image of what you want to achieve? because based on your description I think you need to use something like stackView rather than paragraph style.

Comment: I can't get it to format properly in these windows. But it's quite simple: a line of text -- from a poem, for example -- is aligned to the left margin. On the same line is a line number, which is aligned to the right margin. I'm thinking I might just use a static table view for my page layout. But I'll investigate stack views first.

Answer (score 0):

On another forum I was shown how to add tabs to an attributed string by using its paragraph style. That solved all my problems.

```
let newLine = NSMutableAttributedString(string: citation + "\t", attributes: citationAttributes)
newLine.append(NSAttributedString(string: line.text + "\n", attributes: textAttributes))
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = lineSpacingValue
let tabStop = tabStopValue
style.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: tabStop * 1.1, options: [:])]
newLine.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: newLine.length))
```